# Excel MIN in a group

Tags: excel, macos

Here’s the essence of my question.
Col A has a list of colors, most of the colors are repeated i.e. 20 of the cells have ‘red’, 30 of the cells have ‘blue’, one of the cells has ‘yellow’.
Col B has numbers that are associated with each of the colors from Col A.

What formula/function can I use to find the smallest (MIN) number associated with the color ‘red’?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **Array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A100="red",B1:B100))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you for being there (can you really retire from being a grandfather??...)

Comment: @SBeard still a grandfather, but the kids are now school-age so I no longer babysit.